# How to use Apollo writeQuery in client side ? (Nuxt.js)

Tags: vue.js, graphql, nuxt.js, apollo, apollo-client

I have a Nuxt.js app.

How to use Apollo `writeQuery` method on client side without using mutation?

I want when I click the button (bind to `transfer` method), all products (on backend) to be saved on client server (frontend) cache, and never query the main server.

When a new person visit the page for first time, I don't want any query to be sent to the `backend` server and always use frontend nodejs cache. Even for first visit.

For the backend I use WP-GraphQL

When I use:

```js
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
const getProducts = gql`
query getProducts {
  products {
    nodes {
      name
      id
    }
  }
}

`
export default{

  methods: {
    async transfer() {
      const { data } = await this.$apollo.query({
        query: getProducts,
        fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
      })
      await this.$apollo.writeQuery({
        query: getProducts,
        data,
      })
    },
  },

  async asyncData({ app }) {
    let client = app.apolloProvider.defaultClient
    const { data } = await client.query({
      query: getProducts,
      fetchPolicy: 'cache-only',
    })
    return { products: data }
  },

}
```

It returns error:

```
TypeError: _this.$apollo.writeQuery is not a function
```

Comment: Have you installed Apollo in your Nuxt app?

Comment: @kissu Yes. It's working with `this.$pollo.query()`. But not `this.$pollo.writeQuery()`

Comment: What is `writeQuery` actually? I don't see it anywhere here: https://apollo.vuejs.org/guide/and I never used it myself.